# Connecting two tables into one datagridview using RIGHT JOINT

Tags: c#, sql, join, datagridview

I have got this code below, which should connect 2 tables (ZAJSLUZ and KLISLUZ) but  I need to add into it condition to select only those from ZAJSLUZ where column AKCE = zakce.Text

Would someone improve my code please ?
It gives me error that there is "bad syntax near ="

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from zajsluz",spojeni);
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT     zajsluz.akce ,zajsluz.text,klisluz.pocet FROM zajsluz RIGHT JOIN klisluz ON zajsluz.ID=klisluz.id WHERE zajsluz.akce="+zakce.Text, spojeni);
SDA.Fill(dt);
dtg_ksluzby.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if zakce.Text is a valid string before.

```
string sZakce = string.Empty;
if(zakce != null && zakce.Text != null)
{
  sZakce = zakce.Text;
}
string sQuery = string.Format("SELECT zajsluz.akce ,zajsluz.text,klisluz.pocet FROM zajsluz RIGHT JOIN klisluz ON zajsluz.ID=klisluz.id WHERE zajsluz.akce= '{0}'", sZakce)
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sQuery, spojeni);
```

i also suggest you to use the [using block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) if you work with DataAdapters, so your adapter is disposed automatically.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table", con))
{
   // use your adapter a           
}
```

Comment: It is working well now, but it doesn't select anything :-o even if in column "akce" table zajsluz are values with zakce.Text, But in klsluz are no values with zakce.Text could this be the problém?

Comment: set a breakpoint to the line `sQuery = ...` and check your sql command, prolly zakce.Text is null / empty.

Comment: zakce contains value "999" Does both tables have to contain that value? I need to select only from table "ZAJSLUZ" values which contain in column "AKCE" value "999" (zakce.Text) Im probably using bad query for that ?

Comment: try LEFT JOIN instead of RIGHT JOIN

Comment: It is working well, thanks so much! May I ask where I made a mistake? What was the difference between RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN?

Comment: if you do a right join it means, you select all records from klisluz then join all entries from zajsluz with the same id, if there is no id then the zajsluz columns are joined with null. on left join you select all records from zajsluz then join all entries from klisluz with the same id, if there is no id then the columns are joined with null

Answer (score 1):

Change your line like this.

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT     zajsluz.akce ,zajsluz.text,klisluz.pocet FROM zajsluz RIGHT JOIN klisluz ON zajsluz.ID=klisluz.id WHERE zajsluz.akce='"+zakce.Text+"'", spojeni);
```

Comment: this is not working, it gives me the same error: "bad syntax near="

Comment: @BlazenSip is zajsluz.akce a text field? If yes then see my edit. I have added single quotes.

Comment: I did that, but it says: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: debug and check if zakce or spojeni is null

Comment: It is working well now, but it doesn't select anything :-o even if in column "akce" table zajsluz are values with zakce.Text, But in klsluz are no values with zakce.Text could this be the problém?

Comment: execute the query in database directly and then check if you get the records. If your problem is solved mark it as answer for others.

Comment: I executed but haven't received anythong. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: It means that you dont have data against the query you are executing.

Answer (score 1):

```
...zajsluz.akce=+"zakce.Text,...
```

you might want to change it into

```
...zajsluz.akce='"+zakce.Text+"'",...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your line to

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT zajsluz.akce ,zajsluz.text,klisluz.pocet FROM zajsluz RIGHT JOIN klisluz ON zajsluz.ID=klisluz.id WHERE zajsluz.aakce='" + zakce.Text + "'", spojeni);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT     zajsluz.akce ,zajsluz.text,klisluz.pocet FROM zajsluz RIGHT JOIN klisluz ON zajsluz.ID=klisluz.id WHERE zajsluz.akce= '" +zakce.Text +"'", spojeni);
```